# Deploying example application

Tags: java, glassfish

I am trying to deploy the example form based authentication application to my glassfish server, but everytime I launch the application, I am redirected to yahoo, saying that

```
The requested URL "http://localhost:8080/com-byteslounge-jaas/" cannot be found or is not available. Please check the spelling or try again later.
```

Anyone have any ideas? I downloaded the source straight from here:

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jaas-form-based-authentication-in-tomcat-example

Comment: Try hitting http://localhost:8080 to make sure your server is running

Comment: I tried that, and it says glassfish is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also launch Server Domain Console (`http://localhost:4848` by default) and there, in Applications section, You should have Your app listed. You can see the URL to Your app either by clicking it's name or by clicking Launch link on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The example in your linked article describe the URL is `http://localhost:8080/com-byteslounge-jaas-1.0-SNAPSHOT`, have you ensured you deploy the app to the same context path you're requesting? Check glassfish log to see what context path your app is deployed as

Comment: So what should the context root be?